# How to run MySQL query in fixed database in MySQL at startup of MySql service in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I have to run these query in MySQL everyday in database ABC.

```
set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Is there any way to run these query in MySQL in UBUNTU except runninf from cronjob?

Comment: You can set those from the `my.ini` or `my.cnf` if you have access to that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly execute this from MySQL console

mysql -umyuser databasename -p -A

`set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';`

If you want to do directly you can add it in mysql configuration file follow the steps [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-how-to-permanently-change-sql-mode-in-mysql/)

Comment: Yes but OP wants to do this automatically I think

Comment: Yes @RiggsFolly then OP needs to go with your suggestion and in order to execute your suggestion OP can use [check to update my.ini and my.cnf](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-how-to-permanently-change-sql-mode-in-mysql/)

Comment: After i edit in my.cnf i cannot start/restart mysql. Can you explain proper way to do it automatically ? @VikramSahu

Comment: Check the syntax of your my.cnf file using `/usr/sbin/mysqld <options> --help --verbose`  and it will be helpful if you can share the error you got. Assuming you have root permission because you were able to edit my.cnf and restart `sudo service mysql restart`

Answer (score 0):

First, we find out which configuration file our MySQL installation prefers. For that, we need the binary’s location:

$ which mysqld
/usr/sbin/mysqld

Then, we use this path to execute the lookup:

$ /usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
First, we find out the current sql mode:

mysql -u homestead -psecret -e "select @@sql_mode"

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
We open the configuration file we decided on before (/etc/mysql/my.cnf) and add the following line into the [mysqld] section:

**# ... other stuff will probably be here**

[mysqld]

sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Save, exit, and restart MySQL:

sudo service mysql restart
The SQL mode is permanently changed and I can continue developing the legacy project until I need some additional strictness.